# How can I combine two functions that take the same arguments?

Tags: python

I have a given function

```
def unnorm(x, alpha, beta):
    return (1 + alpha * x + beta * x ** 2)
```

Which I then integrate to find a normalization constant for in a range, and turn it to a lambda function that takes the same parameters as `unnorm`. Now, to create a fit-able object, I combine the functions like this:

```
def normalized(x, alpha, beta):
    return unnorm(x, alpha, beta) * norm(x, alpha, beta)
```

Which is nice and all, but there's still repetition and pulling names from the global namespace.

How can I combine the two functions in a cleaner fashion, without having to re-write parameters? E.g

```
def normalized(func, normalizer):
    return func * normalizer
```

Full code:

```
import sympy
import numpy as np
import inspect

def normalize_function(f, xmin, xmax):
    """
    Normalizes function to PDF in the given range
    """
    # Get function arguments
    fx_args = inspect.getfullargspec(f).args
    # Convert to symbolic notation
    symbolic_args = sympy.symbols(fx_args)
    # Find definite integral
    fx_definite_integral = sympy.integrate(f(*symbolic_args), (symbolic_args[0], xmin, xmax))
    # Convert to a normalization multiplication term, as a real function
    N = sympy.lambdify(expr = 1 / fx_definite_integral, args = symbolic_args)
    return N

def unnorm(x, alpha, beta):
    return (1 + alpha * x + beta * x ** 2)

norm = normalize_function(unnorm, -1, 1)

# How do I condense this to a generic expression?
def normalized(x, alpha, beta):
    return unnorm(x, alpha, beta) * norm(x, alpha, beta)

x = np.random.random(100)

print(normalized(x, alpha = 0.5, beta = 0.5))
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Added minimal example.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see anything wrong with what you are doing now. But for aesthetic purposes, here are a couple of alternatives with some minimal functions.

```
def doubler(x, y, z):
    return 2*(x + y + z)

def halver(x, y, z):
    return 0.5*(x + y + z)

def doubler_halver_sumprod(*args):
    return doubler(*args) * halver(*args)

dhs = lambda *args: doubler(*args) * halver(*args)

doubler_halver_sumprod(1, 2, 3)  # 36
dhs(1, 2, 3)                     # 36
```

If you want a truly extendible, functional approach, extracting arguments once, this could work:

```
from operator import mul, methodcaller
from functools import reduce

def prod(iterable):
    return reduce(mul, iterable, 1)

def doubler(x, y, z):
    return 2*(x + y + z)

def halver(x, y, z):
    return 0.5*(x + y + z)

def dhs2(*args):
    return prod(map(methodcaller('__call__', *args), (doubler, halver)))

def dhs3(*args):
    return prod(f(*args) for f in (doubler, halver))

dhs2(1, 2, 3)  # 36
dhs3(1, 2, 3)  # 36
```

Comment: why wouldn't you just do `prod(f(*args) for f in (doubler, halver))`

Comment: That's another alternative, which also works. I was just going down the purely functional route since this seems to be a functional problem. But I'll add as an alternative.

Comment: If I combine the functions with the lambda, as `dhs` above, either with `*args` or `**kwargs`, fitters (e.g. scipy) will complain that they're unable to determine the number of parameters. It only works if I write `normalized = lambda x, alpha, beta: unnorm(x, alpha, beta) * norm(x, alpha, beta)`

Comment: I couldn't get it working with `**kwarg` either, so I've removed that bit of my post. Also note PEP8: "Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to a name." This would mean `lambda` isn't the best route.

Comment: I think your error is because `inspect` doesn't work as you expect with `lambda`.

Comment: One way would be to re-introduce parameters, like this `def multiplied(x, alpha, beta):
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    args, _, _, values = inspect.getargvalues(frame)

    values.pop("frame")
    return norm(**values) * hypothesis(**values)`, but how do I sneak the two functions around the input? This is getting ugly.

Comment: Yep, this is confusing me. You might find a solution, but when it gets convoluted it's usually a sign to step back and just stick with named functions.

Answer (score 2):

Well, one way would be a decorator that implements `*` and so on for functions:

```
class composable:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        if callable(other):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                return self(*args, **kwargs) * other(*args, **kwargs)
            return self.__class__(wrapper)
        return NotImplemented

@composable
def f(x):
    return 2 * x

@composable
def g(x):
    return x + 1

h = f * g # (2*x) * (x+1)
print(h(2))
# 12
```

You would need to add similar definitions for `__add__`, `__sub__`, `__div__` and probably for the reverse methods `__rmul__` and so on.

Comment: This is a good method, but I would name your class differently because function composition is a technical term which means `f(g(x))`. My only gripe is using `*`notation on functions is ambiguous. But I still like this method. +1

Comment: @jpp  I agree (but could not think of a better name). One could add a `__matmul__` method, so ` f @ g` would be true composition.